# Get selected text contents outside of electron window?

Tags: javascript, electron, clipboard

I have created an electron app that is hidden and running in the background. What I am trying to implement is when a user selects or highlights a text and enters a shortcut key command, the electron app will get that highlighted text and send it to a server.

This leads to two questions that I had:

1. How do I get a selected text that is outside of my electron app? (Currently how I have implemented it is whereby the user inputs the shortcut key command I have configured and this takes the contents of the clipboard and then push it to the server.)
2. Is it possible to override the global shortcut key for "`Cmd+C` or `Ctrl+C`" and add an additional post to server call in the shortcut key command? (I have tried searching on how to do this but found no answers)

Here's what I have so far:

```js
app.on('ready', () => {
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+0', () => {
      console.log('CommandOrControl+0 is pressed')
      keyCommandPressed()
    })

function keyCommandPressed () {
    clipboardText = clipboard.readText([String])
     /* Code to send server call... */

  }
```

Comment: You're looking for Windows keyboard or clipboard hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You should register a local short cut:

```
const electronLocalshortcut = require('electron-localshortcut');
electronLocalshortcut.register(yourWindow, 'CmdOrCtrl+V', () => {
  yourFunction()
});
```

After that you have to use clipboard to read text from Clipboard:
first insert clipboard

```
const {clipboard} = require('electron')
```

then try this:

```
yourFunction()
{
  console.log(clipboard.readText())
}
```